# Is the UPDI pin on AVR DA/AVR Tiny0/... 5V tolerant when VCC@3V3?

Tags: avr, programming, isp

I've a project incorporating an AVR128DA28 which is used with 3V3 peripherals and should be programmed in circuit.

For this I built a [jtag2updi (GitHub)](https://github.com/ElTangas/jtag2updi) adapter using an Arduino Nano.

Since `VCC_target = 3V3` and the "programmer" (Arduino) works with `5V` I need a level shifter; a simple resistor divider (after the 4K7) does not work (I tested it).

But with setting `V_target = 3V3` and UPDI directly connected (through 4K7) it does indeed work. I'm wondering if I damage the µController or my circuit (components) this way since the voltage is `3V3` but the UPDI pin is programmed from the 5V IC with 5V high signal etc.?

I could not find any documentation from Atmel regarding the the allowed max. voltage ratings for the UPDI pin. Any ideas where to find it?

Comment: FWIW I've been programming one ATtiny3227 chip this way for some time - powered by 3.3V and a UPDI 5V - and it seems to be surviving fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have AVR128DA28 to hand, but I have the AVR64DAxx datasheet open: s.37.2 Absolute Maximum Ratings gives all pins positive limit relative to VDD, i.e. there's an ESD clamp diode to VDD.  Testing a AVR64DA64, I indeed measure a diode junction from UPDI to VDD (VDD = 3.3V, it's currently active).

HV programming I think doesn't apply to AVR-Dx, anyway.  Let's see... ah here we go, tinyAVR do:
https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:avr-updi-info
with a pretty obvious explanation -- they're short on pins, so need the extra function offered by HVP.  The rest with dedicated UPDI pins, it seems, don't.